# Create View based on nextval value of sequence

Tags: oracle, view

Can I create a view based on a `nextval` sequence?

I create a view like this:

```
create view seq_agents_nextval 
as
select seq_agents.nextval from dual;
```

From the Oracle documentation I read that it doesn't work like that. Are there any other tricks or tips to create a view with output like that?

Answer (score 2):

your best bet will be a udf in the spirit of the following code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_nv RETURN INTEGER AS
    l_rv NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT seq_agents.nextval
     INTO l_rv
     FROM DUAL
        ;
   RETURN l_rv;
END;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW seq_agents_nextval AS
      SELECT my_nv
        FROM DUAL
           ;
```

otherwise you may query system views to get at least an approximate answer

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW seq_agents_nextval AS
  SELECT last_number + increment_by nv
    FROM ALL_SEQUENCES
   WHERE sequence_owner = '<the_proper_schema_name>'
     AND sequence_name = 'SEQ_AGENTS'
       ;
```

but this value will be of limited use as it may be larger than the actual value by as much as the number of cached values for the sequence times the sequence increment and doesn't take into account the max value and carry-over behavior (the latter two aspects could be fixed).

keep in mind that an arbitrary number of new sequence values may be issued between you querying your view and using the returned value.

hope this helps & regards

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. i already try for the first code, but not the second.. i want to ask, what is the different when i create view from the PL SQL than create view from ALL_SEQUENCE table?

Comment: sorry, i have try the second way,, that view not generate n next value automaticly. if i doing select * from seq_agents_nextval; it doesnt increment the value.